# Document disappears after being inserted into db in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

trying to add to my very simple collection using

```
Template.home.events({    
'click #send-button': function(e, t) {
    e.preventDefault();
    msg = {
        from: Meteor.user()._id,
        to: Meteor.user().penpal,
        sent: new Date(),
        message: $('#message').val()
    };      
    messages.insert(msg);
    console.log(messages.find().fetch());
}
})
```

in collections.js I have

```
messages = new Mongo.Collection('messages');

messages.allow({
    'insert': function (userId,doc) {
      return true; 
}
  });
```

message gets inserted but the console shows that it is being overwritten every time, eg it adds my new message but does not keep all old messages as well. when I try to render messages using

```
Template.home.helpers({
    'messages': function(){
        return messages.find().fetch();
    }
})
```

and then

```
{{#each messages}}...{{/each}}
```

in html I get the messages appearing for the blink of an eye and then disapearing again.

please help! I am desperate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Q&A, it appears you simply need to publish the collection and subscribe to it:

server:

```
Meteor.publish('myMessages',function(){
  const me = this.userId;
  if ( me ){
    return messages.find({ $or: [{ from: me },{ to: me }]});
  }
  this.ready();
});
```

(in the code above the collection is being filtered to messages that are pertinent to the current user, you can define your own filters as required).

client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('myMessages');
```

Comment: I get that, but when I run
    console.log(messages.find().fetch())
it shows only the last object I added in the collection

Comment: The other possibility is that you just don't have pub-sub going. Are you publishing messages (on the server) and subscribing (on the client)? Or do you have the `autopublish` package installed?

Comment: nope! that'll be what it is, how do I implement that?